# Add an NSBundle to finder favorites?

Tags: mac, finder, bundle

I have a bundle myBundle.bundle.  I'd like to add it to the favorites that appear in the left column of the finder.  Is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold down the <kbd>Command</kbd> key while dragging the bundle (or an app, works as well) onto the sidebar.