# Open a bundle in the mac file save dialog?

Tags: macos, mac, filesystems, finder, bundle

I am saving a from an app on my mac.  I have the file save dialog open.  I'd like to save it inside a bundle myBundle.bundle.  I could [add the bundle to the finder favorites](https://superuser.com/questions/645632/add-an-nsbundle-to-finder-favorites), or I could save it elsewhere, then move it into the bundle.  But is there a way to do that directly?  [image]

Comment: When the save dialog is open, command+shift+G will allow you to type the path you want. It's not a perfect solution, because you still have to know where the bundle is on the disk; but it's one alternative.

Comment: @Kent That part on Cmd-Shift-G should probably be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When the save dialog is open, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> will allow you to type the path you want to go to.  It requires you to either know the full path (and type it in correctly), or have copied the full path to the clipboard.  So, there's likely still some more work to be done in turning this into a simple workflow.